# JavaScript adding text after pageloads in a paragraph

Tags: javascript

HTML(can't change this):

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Question 8</legend>
      <p>
        Create a new "p" element with the text "New Element", and add it to #question-8
      </p>
      <div id="question-8"></div>
    </fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
var node = document.createElement('p');
node.setAttribute('id', 'q8');

var content = document.createTextNode("New Element");
node.appendChild(content);

console.log(node);
```

I am trying to get the text New Element to show up in a paragraph with the ID of q8. I must use non-obtrusive JavaScript.  In my console window it shows up correctly, but it does not sow up in my HTML. How do I get it to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Something close to this should work.

The code will only run once the whole document is loaded.

It will get the element in question by its id, then append a paragraph element to it, which in turn gets a text node with the desired content appended.

Since appendChild returns the child node we need to get its parentElement to pass to the upper appendChild call.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
    if (event.target.readyState !== "complete") {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('question-8')
    .appendChild(document.createElement('p')
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Element')).parentElement);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to do this:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body; // never use document or document.body again
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e); // never use document.getElementById() again
}
E('question-8').innerHTML = "<p id='q8'>New Element</p>";
```

Of course, you could do this:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function C(t){
  return doc.createElement(t);
}
var q8 = C('p'), txt = doc.createTextNode('New Element'), qest8 = E('question-8');
q8.id = 'q8', q8.appendChild(txt); quest8.appendChild(q8);
```