# Javascript onclick not firing (firebug doesn't complain)

Tags: javascript

I might be a little tired but it's 20 mins I look at it but can't see why one of the two divs fires the alert and the other one doesn't.

```
<html>
<body>
<br>
<div id="hideMenu2">Hide</div>
<br>
<div id="showTop2">Show</div>
    <script>
      var showTop2 = document.getElementById('showTop2');
      var hideMenu2 = document.getElementById('hideMenu2');
          showTop2.onclick = function() 
      {
          alert("Show");
      };
      hideMenu2.onClick = function()
      {
          alert("Hide!");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: should be `onclick = function() {...}` all lower case

Comment: arghhhhh :) thank you.. but why doesn't firebug notify the onclick method doesn't exist??? That would have helped...

Comment: So, what did you mean by "letter casing is ok" - it clearly isn't in your example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: @sarah.ferguson the thing is that it's OK to assign something to a new property name on any object. It's not really an "error", even though it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Make sure document is fully loaded before code is run. See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294187/javascript-adding-text-after-pageloads-in-a-paragraph/20294516#20294516

Comment: Now I see why it didn't complain.. LOL I hate JS!

Answer (score 1):

The key word `onClick` should be `onclick`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54SNZ/)**

```
  var showTop2 = document.getElementById('showTop2');
  var hideMenu2 = document.getElementById('hideMenu2');
      showTop2.onclick = function() 
  {
      alert("Show");
  };
  hideMenu2.onclick = function()
  {
      alert("Hide!");
  };
```